# A simple question on Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Ok so my assignment is:

> The mills at some carpet company produce, on average, $1$ flaw in every $500$ yards produced, and the carpeting is sold in $100$ yard rolls. If the number of flaws in a roll follows a Poisson distribution, and the quality department rejects any roll with $2$ or more flaws, what percent of rolls is rejected?

Am I to use $\lambda = 1/5$? And, if so, is my proposed solution $100\cdot(1 - P(X=0) - P(X=1))$ correct?

Comment: That sounds right to me.

Comment: Thanks, I was debating using λ = 1/500, but  when I re-read the question, 1/5 seemed better, although I still had my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all doubt, note that you are told that "the number of **flaws in a roll** follows a Poisson distribution."  You are also asked for "What percent of **rolls** is rejected?"  So the Poisson rate should be expressed in units of flaws per roll.

If there are 100 yards in a roll and the error rate is 1 per 500 yards, this is equivalent to a Poisson rate of 1 per 5 rolls or $1/5$ per roll, hence $\lambda = 1/5$.

When set up this way, the Poisson random variable with $\lambda = 1/5$ counts the random number of flaws found in a single roll.  This is precisely what you want, since if this number is at least $2$, the roll is rejected.